# XSL: "for each select" function does not work correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

I got an .xml file that Im supposed to convert into an html file using XSL.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<Company>

<SectionA>
   <Employee>Peter Barry</Employee>
   <Employee>Lisa Stewart</Employee>
   <Employee>Harry Rogers</Employee>
</SectionA>

<SectionB>
   <Employee>Tom Riddle</Employee>
</SectionB>

</Company>
```

In my html file the output should look like this:
"Peter Barry, Lisa Stewart, Harry Rogers".

The problem is that the for-each function does not work in this case!
My code in the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

<h2>All</h2>

<table>

<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="Company/SectionA">
    <xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>


</table>


</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the html it only shows the name of the first employee (that is "Peter Barry"). How do I get this right in order to show every element?

Comment: Please show a **reproducible** example. We cannot tell what your code does, without knowing in which context it is being executed. That said, an empty  `xsl:for-each` will not do anything. Put something in it, e.g. `xsl:value-of`. -- Also, please show your expected output **as code**.

Comment: Sorry, I put both codes now into my post now!

Comment: Incidentally, `<td>` elements need to be inside a `<tr>`.

Comment: Also, if you have any control over the source, don't name elements 'SectionA', 'SectionB'. Instead name each 'Section' and use an attribute to specify which one, such as `<Section id='A'>`, it's much easier to write XSLT/XPath for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a row for each employee in Section A, than use:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Company/SectionA/Employee">
            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

The way you have it now, you are in the context of `SectionA` and `<xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>` returns the value of the **first** child employee only - that's how it works in XSLT 1.0. Plus you're only creating one table cell and no rows.

Answer (score 1):

Using for-each isn't the best option in this case, it would be better to define a template for handling each employee, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>All</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Company/SectionA"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SectionA">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employee">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>           
</xsl:stylesheet>
```